# DreamSpark, 2 copies of each software? Or up to 2 specific titles only?

Tags: dreamspark

The EULA states that you can install up to two copies of software. Is this simply two copies of the same title, or does it mean that you can only install say, windows 7 and visual studio, and if you tried to install anything else you would have used up your two installs? I'm wondering because I recently got access to DreamSpark Premium and there's several things I'm interested in trying out but not sure if I can download more than two different applications or not.

Comment: The license is pretty clear; you might want to read it again

Comment: @Brent You missing, "or two copies of the same product key?" You'll have to read all the EULAs for the software too though if you're  worried you're doing something wrong. It's not any two items from library of available titles, if that's what you're wondering. If you can generate a key, obviously you can use it... But I don't think SU wants to answer legal questions, so I think this is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Go with the "literal interpretation".  Two "copies" is always the same software.
Note that this does not always produce the intended result but stiff biscuits, the literal understanding is valid for a "meeting of minds" test.

The most interesting example of this kind of EULA is the difference between OEM and retail copies of Microsoft Office from about a decade ago.  For some installs on multi boot computers it was not permitted to have even another licensed copy on the same physical machine. (So a XP/Vista/7/8 multi boot build could only have Microsoft Office running for one of them according to the literal interpretation).